VDB visibility is affected by samples in Eevee, how avoid?
Im having an issue with 4.2 in Eevee, where the VDB is affected by the the render samples. if i go above 12 or so, the VDB is almost transparent. The intended visual effect is what it appears to be at sample 2, however obviously i cannot keep it at 2 samples! :)
Any ideas?
Thank you!
David

